# Emacs: can "replace-regex" replace all \command{foo} to foo?

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm editing a Latex file which has many such things:

```
\command{a}
\command{b}
...
```

My question is how in emacs I can change them to

```
a
b
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple, execute `M-x replace-regexp`, then type `^.*{\(.*\)}.*$`, hit Enter, type `\1`, and hit Enter one more time. You can fine-tune the regex to be less greedy or be more specific if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general solution which also works for things like

```text
multiple commands on the same line: \com{a} \com{b}
command \com{a} goes in the arbitrary place in the line
```

find: `\\[^{]+{\([^}]*\)}`, replace to `\1`.